# How to return value instead of related object.id in DynamicFieldsModelSerializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework there is possibility to create serializer capable to [Dynamically modifying fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields). Is there a chance to get `value` instead of related `object.id`?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are talking about a Foreign Key's field.
Generally in Django the format is `ForeignKey__Field` (two underscores), this is used **everywhere** *(that isn't a template)*

So using the general format provided in the links, this should work!

```py
# Example Model:
#
# class Sale(models.Model):
#   sale_number = Int
#   customer = ForeignKey -> User

class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Sale
         fields = ['id', 'sale_number', 'customer__username', 'customer__email']
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Here AddressModel have (city,state,country) as a ForeignKey() if you want to display object dict instead of ForeignKey() you can add SerializerMethodField() in Serializer like this

```
class AddressModel(models.Model):
    address_types = (('Office','Office'),('Home','Home'), ('Other', 'Other'))
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_tags = models.CharField(choices=address_types,max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default='Other')
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(CitiesModel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    state = models.ForeignKey(StatesModel, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    country = models.ForeignKey(CountryModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='postal code')
    is_default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AddressSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    country_obj = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    state_obj = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    city_obj = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_country_obj(self, obj):
        return {'id': obj.country.id, 'name': obj.country.country_name}

    def get_state_obj(self, obj):
        return {'id': obj.state.id, 'name': obj.state.name}
    
    def get_city_obj(self, obj):
        return {'id': obj.city.id, 'name': obj.city.name}


    
    class Meta:
        model = AddressModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### Json Output

```json
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [
        
        {
            "id": 134,
            "country_obj": {
                "id": 104,
                "name": "India"
            },
            "state_obj": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Maharashtra"
            },
            "city_obj": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Mumbai"
            },
            "full_name": "NATURAL STORE",
            "address_tags": "Office",
            "mobile": "+918888888888",
            "address_line_1": "37 - GF, Princess Street",
            "address_line_2": "Gopal Niwas Building, Marine Line East",
            "landmark": "Marine Lines East",
            "postal_code": "400002",
            "is_default": true,
            "city": 2,
            "state": 2,
            "country": 104
        },
        {
            "id": 135,
            "country_obj": {
                "id": 104,
                "name": "India"
            },
            "state_obj": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Maharashtra"
            },
            "city_obj": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Mumbai"
            },
            "full_name": "NATURAL STORE",
            "address_tags": "Office",
            "mobile": "+919999999999",
            "address_line_1": "Shop No 5, Vaishali Shopping Centre",
            "address_line_2": "Nr Kalaniketan, Vaikunthlal Mehta Rd, Juhu",
            "landmark": "Juhu",
            "postal_code": "400049",
            "is_default": true,
            "city": 2,
            "state": 2,
            "country": 104
        }
    ],
    "message": "Address successfully displayed"
}
```